# MYSQL PHP count lines in two tables with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to count entries (lines) from two tables WHERE (in both) user_id is 12 and club is 5,8,19. I need to receive values (or array it does not matter) for each club, example (5=>24, 8=>78, 19=>56). How can I write this query please?

thank you.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your tables? how do they connect to each other, what kind of relationship they have (1:1, 1:n, n:m)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your tables are: user and club.

```
SELECT c.club_id, COUNT(*)
FROM user u, club c
WHERE u.user_id = 12 
      AND c.club_id IN (5,8,19)
      AND u.club_id = c.club_id
GROUP BY c.club_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_rows FROM my_table WHERE user_id = 12 AND club_id in (5,8,19) GROUP BY club_id
```